# return a string based on conditions without using if/else

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an object something like

```
const myObj = {
  hasError: true/false,
  someProp: 'someValue'
}
```

Based on this object I have four conditions to evaluate:

1. Object is empty
2. hasError is true
3. has error is false and someProp is undefined
4. has error is false and some prop is defined

I'd like to find a nice and readable way to evaluate these 4 conditions without resorting to if/else.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking into ternary operators?

Comment: For conditionals, unless you rely on your own construct, you really only have ternarys and if statements; and ternarys only work if your trying to choose between exactly 2 options. I'd say just use if/else, or create some abstraction that hides the if/else.

Comment: Evaluate how? If you want to do different things, you'll need an if/else, or a switch, but if/else seems more readable here. If you just want to check everything, as in `if ( myObj.hasError || myObj.someProp === 'something' )` it makes no sense, as all together they cover pretty much every variation.

Comment: You need `if`/`else` (or the more expressive `switch`) statements, because there is no pattern matching or guards in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the conditions and ensuing actions as an array of condition/action tuples:

```
const actions = [
  {if: o => !Object.keys(o).length, then: () => "empty"},
  {if: o => o.hasError,             then: () => "hasError"},
  {if: o => !('someProp' in o),     then: () => "someProp is undefined"},
  {if: o => true,                   then: () => "got everything"}
];
```

Now `find` the first matching condition and execute the associated logic:

```
actions.find(action => action.if(myObj)).then()
```

If it is not guaranteed that at least one condition will be satisfied, then you would need to check the result of the `find` to make sure it's not null.

Although this can be an elegant solution in some cases, you should have some good reason for doing things this way, such as wanting to pass around these condition/action objects, instead of just using regular old `if`/`else`.

Comment: All the effort only to avoid `if`/`else`? This only makes sense if you need first class or lazy evaluated conditions.

Comment: @ftor Well, I was just answering the question, not opining on the merits of avoiding `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

The nice and readable way **is** with an `if/else` condition

```
if ( Object.keys(myObj).length === 0 ) { 

    // Object is empty

} else if ( myObj.hasError ) {

    // hasError is true

} else if ( ! myObj.someProp ) {

    // has error is false and someProp is undefined

} else {

    // has error is false and some prop is defined

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
function errMsg(obj_){
    return !obj_ && 'Object is empty'
          || obj_.hasError && 'Error!'
          || !obj_.hasError && 
                   ( 
                     typeof obj_.foo === 'undefined'? 
                            'foo is undefined': 
                            'foo is defined'
                   )
          ;
}

errMsg()                   // "Object is empty"
errMsg({hasError:true})   // "Error!"
errMsg({hasError:false})  // "foo is undefined"
errMsg({hasError:false,foo:'bar'})// "foo is defined"
```

Comment: `obj_.foo === undefined`.

Comment: @OP:  I am curious to know what motivates you to avoid an if/else construct?  Is there some constraint in the code or is it a matter of style or a challenge?   I am not questioning your design decision, just curious :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what's wrong with `if/then`, but how about a `switch` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)?

```js
const myObj = {
  hasError: false,
  someProp : "something"
}

switch (true) {
 case Object.keys(myObj).length === 0:
    console.log("Object is empty.");
    break;
 case myObj.hasError === true:
    console.log("hasError is true");
    break;    
 case !myObj.hasError && !myObj.someProp:
    console.log("hasError is false and someProp is undefined");
    break;
 case !myObj.hasError && myObj.someProp !== undefined:
    console.log("hasError is false and someProp is defined");
    break;
}
```

Comment: This particular idiom (`switch (true)`) is useful in some cases, but some people think it's an anti-pattern, and one has to be careful because the internal `switch` logic uses strict equality checking. Also, it is vaguely intellectually dissatisfying to have repeat `!myObj.hasError`.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't disagree at all. But, for whatever reason, the OP asked for another way to to logic without if/then.